# Runtime error 91. Trying to loop .navigate for several values in one sub

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

First off, thank you stackoverflow users for helping me get the code correct for one city (MSP). But, now I am trying to loop it and extract data for several cities. For now, just MSP, SLC, LAX and ATL. I will need to add more later. Also, if I ever need to move locations, I may go from the 10-15ish flights a day we have now to 40ish, and I understand this will get really slow.

Anyways, while trying to get flight data for several cities, I have to continually adjust the "For i = 0 To 40" on each one so it doesn't give me a run-time error 91. I have concluded thus far, that slc needs to be at "For i = 0 To 35" when msp is set to go till 40. When the code makes it's way to atl, I can not find a number that works, it will step all the way till the last do loop and give me that error.

In sum, I am trying to pull flight data for several cities with one button, and will have to organize the data based on the time (i still need to convert the am/pm to military time and sort). If you try the code out, it will give you msp and slc flight data but, not atl (line 67  a = Doc.getElem...). And I will have to add more cities later.

```
Sub populateFlightInfo()
'declare variables
        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Dim i As Integer, f As Integer, count As Integer
        Dim cityPair As String

    For q = 0 To 4
        If q = 0 Then
        cityPair = "MSP"
        GoTo msp
        ElseIf q = 1 Then
        cityPair = "SLC"
        GoTo slc
        ElseIf q = 2 Then
        cityPair = "ATL"
        GoTo atl
        Else
        GoTo terminate
        End If
msp:
        'run internet explorer
        Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
        count = 0
        IE.navigate "https://assistive.usablenet.com/tt/www.delta.com/flightinfo/viewFlightSchedules.action?departureAirportCode=bzn&flightDate=" _
        & "2015-08-23" & "&arrivalAirportCode=" & cityPair
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Set Doc = IE.document

        For i = 0 To 40
        On Error GoTo second
           a = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")(i)
        Next
        GoTo second

slc:
        'run internet explorer
        Dim IG As New InternetExplorer
        count = 1
        IG.navigate "https://assistive.usablenet.com/tt/www.delta.com/flightinfo/viewFlightSchedules.action?departureAirportCode=bzn&flightDate=" _
        & "2015-08-23" & "&arrivalAirportCode=" & cityPair
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IG.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Set Doc = IG.document

        For i = 0 To 35
        On Error GoTo second
           a = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")(i)
        Next
        GoTo second
atl:
        'run internet explorer
        Dim IY As New InternetExplorer
        count = 2
        IY.navigate "https://assistive.usablenet.com/tt/www.delta.com/flightinfo/viewFlightSchedules.action?departureAirportCode=bzn&flightDate=" _
        & "2015-08-23" & "&arrivalAirportCode=" & cityPair
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IY.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Set Doc = IY.document

        For i = 0 To 50
        On Error GoTo second
           a = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")(i)
        Next
        GoTo second
second:
        offSet = 0
            For r = 0 To (i / 9) - 1

                flt = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")((r * 9) + offSet).innerText
                dep = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")((r * 9) + 2 + offSet).innerText)
                cty = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")((r * 9) + 3 + offSet).innerText

                Range("F35").End(xlUp).offSet(1, 0).Value = Right(Replace(flt, " *", ""), 6)
                Range("F35").End(xlUp).offSet(0, 1).Value = Trim(Left(dep, 7))
                Range("F35").End(xlUp).offSet(0, 2).Value = cty
            If InStr(flt, Chr(42)) > 0 Then
                offSet = offSet + 1
            End If
            Next r
        If count = 0 Then
        IE.Quit
        ElseIf count = 1 Then
        IG.Quit
        ElseIf count = 2 Then
        IY.Quit
        Else
        End If

    Next q
terminate:


End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of hard-coding your loops, use an appropriate counter. Also, your use of `GoTo` statements is far from optimal. Give me a few minutes to make some suggestions to improve this.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I will start playing around with a counter.

Comment: the `.GetElementsByClassName` should return a collection which has a `.Count` property, I think. You're misusing `On Error Resume Next`, too :)

Comment: Or you could use `For/Each` loop. That is what I will implement... still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you are iterating through your elements if you don't know how many there will be, for example use a collection instead:

```
Dim divColl As Object
'// rest of code ...
Set divColl = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")

For i = 0 To divColl.Length - 1
    a = divColl(i)
Next i
'// rest of code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding your loops `For i = 0 to 50` (etc) use the appropriate counter:

```
For i = 0 to Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell").Length - 1
```

HOWEVER, you're not even doing anything with the content of that loop, where you assign to the variable `a`. So those loops, as well as the assignment to `a`, are totally unnecessary.

I've streamlined this code so that it avoids the spaghetti effect of `GoTo` loops, and also the misuse of `On Error Resume Next`.  The main procedure `populateFlightInfo` initializes an array of city codes, which you can modify as needed. Then it uses a `For Each` loop and passes each city name and date to another procedure which pulls out the information. YOu can modify that to print to the worksheet, right now it simply displays msgbox to show you the information.

This only uses one instance of Internet Explorer rather than the several which you were creating potentially. This code should be much more compartementalized and easier to modify for future needs.  Let me know if you have any Q's.

```
Option Explicit

Const baseURL As String = "https://assistive.usablenet.com/tt/www.delta.com/flightinfo/viewFlightSchedules.action?departureAirportCode=bzn&flightDate="

Sub populateFlightInfo()
'declare variables

        Dim strDate As String
        Dim cityList As Variant
        Dim city As Variant

        'Assign the date string:
        strDate = "2015-08-23"

        'Create an array/list of the cities, modify as needed
        cityList = Array("MSP", "SLC", "ATL")

        'Iterate over the array defined above:
        For Each city In cityList

            'Call another procedure to do the IE automation/retrieval
            Call GetFlightInfo(city, strDate)


        Next

End Sub

Sub GetFlightInfo(city As Variant, strDate As String)
        Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
        Dim url As String
        Dim elements As Object
        Dim ele As Object
        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Dim r As Integer
        Dim offset As Integer
        Dim flt$, dep$, cty$

        'Construct the full url:
        url = baseURL & strDate & "&arrivalAirportCode=" & city

        'Navigate to the URL
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate url
            Do
                DoEvents
            Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Set Doc = IE.document

        Set elements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("schedulesTableCell")

        'iterate over the elements collection:
        ' and display flight info in msgbox
        ' you can modify to print on the worksheet
        Do


            flt = elements(r + offset).innerText
            dep = Trim(elements(r + 2 + offset).innerText)
            cty = elements(r + 3 + offset).innerText

            Debug.Print "City: " & city & vbTab & flt & vbTab & dep & vbTab & cty

            'Find the asterisk and adjust the offset
            If InStr(flt, Chr(42)) > 0 Then offset = offset + 1

            'MsgBox flt & vbTab & dep & vbTab & cty

            i = i + 1
            r = i * 9
        Loop While Not (r + offset) >= elements.Length - 1

        IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: I have not played with it yet to try it myself but, it is still giving me a run-time error 91. This time though, it is after the first set of flights (MSP) and on line 57 where it tries to retrieve variable flt info for (SLC). All I modified was I commented the msgbox out and added 3 range lines back in to put the content back onto the page

Comment: Can you explain what you were attempting to do with this: `For r = 0 To (i / 9) - 1`?? I was trying to clean that up, but unsure what your intent was.

Comment: I see what causes the error and have made a small revision to account for that....

Comment: Thank you, just have to modify the offset back to what i had, the (r * 9) + offset inside the flt, dep and cty and it worked! thank you.

Comment: Cheers, if this has solved the problem do consider marking the answer as "Accepted" :)